# Python Ship Packages With Py File

Tags: python

I have made a python script which requires several packages that are unavailable at my school, I have no access to command prompt and preferably do not want to install them locally. Is there any way I can get all the packages my script needs and take them with me to use just like I would normally, opening the python script on the desktop?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you need to do that? Generally speaking if it's because you're not allowed to use certain packages it'd be very very obvious from your code that you're using those packages.

Comment: It just the requests library but I don't have access to install it

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of installing a [virtual environment](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/)?
you can also try

```
import sys
sys.path.append('insert the location to your scripts')
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Is the sys.path.append permanent or just for this script?

Comment: @bilbo `sys.path.append` is just for the current run of the script.